# Вызов QMessageBox::critical()

Tags: c++, qt

Есть класс, не унаследованный от QWidget. Представляет собой класс реализации доступа к БД. При попытке вызова QMessageBox::critical() выдаёт ошибку, ругается, что я задаю в качестве родителя объект класса, не наследника QWidget. Как мне тогда вызвать окно с текстом ошибки?

```
QList<Group> result;
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("connection");
QSqlQuery query(db);
if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM `prod_group`")) QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Ошибка"), query.lastError().text());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
QMessageBox::critical(0, tr("Ошибка"), query.lastError().text());
```